# Understanding an example of a both open and closed set.

Tags: general-topology

In Armstrong's Basic Topology, the example is that take the space $X$ whose points are those points $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{E}^2$ such that $x\geq1$ or $x\leq-1$, and whose topology is that induced from $\mathbb{E}^2$. The subset of $X$ consisting of those points with positive first coordinate is both open and closed in $X$. This subset is not open in $\mathbb{E}^2$, but I just cannot figure out why it is open in $X$. I think $\mathbb{E}^2$ refers to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$ in this book.

Comment: How do you define the induced topology?

Comment: Its not open in $\mathbb{E}^2$ but you're trying to figure out why it is open in $\mathbb{E}^2$?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{E}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ in this book and the induced topology is the usual topology in $\mathbb{E}^2$.

Comment: And what is the usual topology in $\Bbb E^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a set $\ A\ $ is open in $\ X\ $ with respect to to the topology induced by $\ \mathbb{E}^2\ $ if and only if there's an open set $\ \mathscr{A}\ $ of $\ \mathbb{E}^2\ $ such that $\ A=$$\,\mathscr{A}\cap X\ .$ The set you're wondering about is the intersection $\ B=$$\,X\,\cap$$\,\big((0,\infty)\times$$\,\mathbb{E}^1\big)\ ,$ and  $\ (0,\infty)\times\mathbb{E}^1\ $ is an open subset of $\ \mathbb{E}^2\ .$ Therefore $\ B\ $ is open in $\ X\ $ with respect to to the topology induced by $\ \mathbb{E}^2\ .$

Comment: I apologize for my mistakes in my question, the original text says the subset of $X$
 consisting of those points with positive first coordinate that is both open and closed in $X$

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer in the light of your revisions to the question.